# What do the non-white ranks represent?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

On the multiplayer scoreboard, some number ranks display in colors (red, blue, green) as opposed to white (like me). Also there aren't three-digit numbers, but there are medals (wings?) that also come in colors. I can surmise that the wings represent level 100 and the colors represent "prestige-ing." I don't remember this from *Gears* at launch. What's the deal?

Answer (score 1):

The coloured ranks were introduced as part of the Fenix Rising DLC.

The Re-Up System allows players that have reached level 100 "re-up" for another tour of duty, which resets experience and rank, however, other progress in the game will be saved.

Players can "re-up" up to three times, the different colours represent how many times a player has done this. The levels are as follows (in ascending order of prestige):

- Red
- Green
- Gold

There are also achievements associated with choosing to re-up (*Time to Re-up!* and *Again!*), as well as unique weapon skins.

More information can be found on the [Gears of War wikia page](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Fenix_Rising), if you're interested.